# Sending file by chunk using HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpwebrequest

I have a very simple task. In my ASP.NET Core 2 I should accept file url from user and resend file binary data to my inner microservice. I'm trying to do this without storing file on disk or in memory. Just accept file chunk and send it network. I've written this code

```
int bytesToRead = 4096;
byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];

// getting download stream
HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(fileUrl);
HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();
if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
{
    fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;
}

// getting upload stream
var downloadStream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();

HttpWebRequest uploadRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("url_to_send_file_data");
uploadRequest.Method = "POST";
uploadRequest.ContentLength = fileResp.ContentLength;
uploadRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

var uploadStream = await uploadRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();

int length = 0;
do
{
    length = await downloadStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

    await uploadStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, length);
    await uploadStream.FlushAsync();
}
while (length > 0);

// all file data in uploadStream._buffer so far
uploadStream.Close();

// only in this point request actually start
var result = await uploadRequest.GetResponseAsync();

downloadStream.Close();
```

According to manuals and articles the request should be started after `uploadRequest.GetRequestStream()` and all `uploadStream.WriteAsync()` calls should write data directly in network. But acctually all file data has written in `uploadStream._buffer` and went to network only after `GetResponseAsync()` calling.

I was trying to play with `uploadRequest.SendChunked` properties and with the HTTP headers but out of luck.

Will he helpfull for any suggestion.

P.S. Yes, I know about `using(){}` :)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not exactly sure what you are doing there but assuming you have an [`IFormFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-2.1) from a POST request that contains your file, you can just use its stream to pass on to the request using a HttpClient:

```
private async Task SendFileAsync(IFormFile file, HttpClient client)
{
    var url = "url_to_send_file_data";

    using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.POST, url))
    {
        request.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

This will reuse the incoming file stream directly and use it for the outgoing request.